# Find that solution $ϕ$ which satisfies $ϕ(0) = 1, ϕ'(0) = 2$ for $y'' = 3x + 1$.

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Find the particular solution to the following *second order linear ordinary differential equation* that satisfies the $ϕ$

> $y'' = 3x + 1$, $ϕ(0) = 1, ϕ'(0) = 2$

**My solution:**

> $y' = \frac{3x^2}{2} + x + c_1$
>
> $y = \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2} + c_1x + c_2$
>
> $ϕ(0) = 1 => c_2 = 1$ so $y = \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2} + x + 1$
>
> $ϕ'(0) = 2 => c_1 = 2$ so $y = \frac{3x^2}{2} + x+ 2$

I checked the back of my textbook and it has a different answer than mine. Am I doing something wrong here? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Why are we using both $\phi$ and $y$ for the same function?

Comment: @Moo $ϕ(x) =  \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2} + 2x + 1$

Comment: I get the same as the book.

Comment: After your first step you can conclude that $c_1=\phi^\prime(0)=2$. In your third step you can only conclude that $c_2=1$. What is this variable $c$ which you use in step $3$?

Comment: @Moo how?                              .............................

Comment: don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my derivation of your book's solution:
$$
y''=3x+1\implies y'=3/2x^2+x+c\implies y=\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+cx+d
$$
then boundary conditions yield $d=1$ since 
$$
y(0)=\frac{0^3}{2}+\frac{0^2}{2}+c*0+d=d=1
$$
and similarly
$$
y'(0)=2=c
$$
and thus 
$$
y(x)=\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+2x+1
$$