# Find that solution $ϕ$ which satisfies $ϕ(0) = 0, ϕ(1) = 3$ for $y'' = 3x + 1$.

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Find the particular solution to the following *second order linear ordinary differential equation* that satisfies the $ϕ$

> $y'' = 3x + 1$, $ϕ(0) = 0, ϕ(1) = 3$

**My solution:**

> $y' = \frac{3x^2}{2} + x + c_1$
>
> $y = \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2} + c_1x + c_2$
>
> $ϕ(0) = 0 => 0 + 0 + 0 + c_2 = 0 => c_2 = 0$
>
> $ϕ(1) = 3 => \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + c_1 + c_2 = 3$

I am in trouble in step 4 where I need to find the value of $c_1$. How do I go about finding this? Should I do this: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + c_1 + c_2 = 3 => 1 + 2c = 3 => c_1 = 1$? Please help me!

Comment: Your calculation is correct.  You already know that $c_2=0$ so you are free to substitute that into the last equation.

Comment: @lulu I got $c_2 = 0 $ for the first equation. I cannot just substitute that, can I?

Comment: You absolutely can!  Think of it as a system of two linear equations:  $c_2=0$  and $c_1+c_2=2$.

Comment: this is almost identical to the question you already asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130824/find-that-solution-%CF%95-which-satisfies-%CF%950-1-%CF%950-2-for-y-3x-1/2130838#2130838

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find that solution $ϕ$ which satisfies $ϕ(0) = 1, ϕ'(0) = 2$ for $y'' = 3x + 1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130824/find-that-solution-%cf%95-which-satisfies-%cf%950-1-%cf%950-2-for-y-3x-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have c2=0 substitute it and find c1.

Comment: This is not really an answer. Explain the steps to the OP!

Comment: @TheCount I was just guiding them. At that moment I was unable to comment due to low reputation, otherwise, I would have used the comment section. A Similar question was asked previously by the same user.